# 360 фотографии и видео в Unreal Engine 4

Tags: c++, камера, gallery, photo, unreal-engine-4

Ребят. Всем доброго времени суток. Я столкнулся с такой проблемой: Хочу сделать 360 фотографии галерею на Unreal Engine, но не знаю как. До этого я делал её на Unity, теперь хочу сделать тоже самое на Unreal. Помогите пожалуйста. Если у кого есть исходник хотя бы с 1 фотографией - скиньте пожалуйста. И посоветуйте пожалуйста мануалы, книги, статьи и видео-уроки по данной теме.